# ReactNative AsyncStorage combined with async/await. Is "await" required for setItem operations?

Tags: async-await, react-native, ecmascript-6

I am building a class to handle storage in React Native and want to use the async/await pattern. The getItem works, I am not sure if I need to asyncify the setItem. Do I?

```
class StorageLayer {

  static async getStorageKey(key) {
    try{
      let value = await AsyncStorage.getItem(key);
      return value;
    }
    catch(e){
      return null;
    }
  }

  static setStorageKey(key, value) {
    console.log("setStorageKey key ->", key, value);

    return AsyncStorage.setItem(key, value);
  }


}
```

vs:

```
...
static async setStorageKey(key, value) {
    console.log("setStorageKey key ->", key, value);

    return AsyncStorage.setItem(key, value);
}
```

Comment: If `setItem` already returns a promise, it doesn't make a difference here.

Answer (score 1):

The issue would be the async callatack. If an exception was thrown in `setItem`, `setStorageKey` would not be in the callstack if you didn't use await.

If that's acceptable, await can be omitted here.

Comment: So do I:

`let success = await AsyncStorage.setItem(key, value);`

To add it? same pattern?

Comment: You don't have to assign the result to a temporary variable, you can simply `return await AsyncStorage.setItem()`